# Compare row entries between multiple consecutive columns

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

I have a dataset with observed locations (Zone) at specific times of day on multiple dates:

```
library(data.table)
sample = structure(list(Time = structure(c(1573430400, 1573430401, 1573516800, 
1573516801, 1573603200, 1573603201, 1573689600, 1573689601, 1573776000, 
1573776001), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Zone = c("Tier_2", "Tier_2", "Tier_4", "Tier_4", "Ramp_Nestbox", 
    "Ramp_Nestbox", "Tier_4", "Tier_4", "Tier_4", "Tier_4")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), sorted = "Time")

sample
                   Time         Zone
 1: 2019-11-11 00:00:00       Tier_2
 2: 2019-11-11 00:00:01       Tier_2
 3: 2019-11-12 00:00:00       Tier_4
 4: 2019-11-12 00:00:01       Tier_4
 5: 2019-11-13 00:00:00 Ramp_Nestbox
 6: 2019-11-13 00:00:01 Ramp_Nestbox
 7: 2019-11-14 00:00:00       Tier_4
 8: 2019-11-14 00:00:01       Tier_4
 9: 2019-11-15 00:00:00       Tier_4
10: 2019-11-15 00:00:01       Tier_4
```

Now I would like to calculate the amount of equal locations at the time points between **consecutive** days.

For this I thought it would be easiest to switch from a long to a wide format by help of separate Date and Time vectors:

```
sample[, TimeStamp := as.ITime(Time)]
sample[, DateStamp := as.IDate(Time)]
sample
                   Time         Zone TimeStamp  DateStamp
 1: 2019-11-11 00:00:00       Tier_2  00:00:00 2019-11-11
 2: 2019-11-11 00:00:01       Tier_2  00:00:01 2019-11-11
 3: 2019-11-12 00:00:00       Tier_4  00:00:00 2019-11-12
 4: 2019-11-12 00:00:01       Tier_4  00:00:01 2019-11-12
 5: 2019-11-13 00:00:00 Ramp_Nestbox  00:00:00 2019-11-13
 6: 2019-11-13 00:00:01 Ramp_Nestbox  00:00:01 2019-11-13
 7: 2019-11-14 00:00:00       Tier_4  00:00:00 2019-11-14
 8: 2019-11-14 00:00:01       Tier_4  00:00:01 2019-11-14
 9: 2019-11-15 00:00:00       Tier_4  00:00:00 2019-11-15
10: 2019-11-15 00:00:01       Tier_4  00:00:01 2019-11-15

sample_wide = dcast(sample, formula = TimeStamp ~ DateStamp, value.var = "Zone")
sample_wide
   TimeStamp 2019-11-11 2019-11-12   2019-11-13 2019-11-14 2019-11-15
1:  00:00:00     Tier_2     Tier_4 Ramp_Nestbox     Tier_4     Tier_4
2:  00:00:01     Tier_2     Tier_4 Ramp_Nestbox     Tier_4     Tier_4
```

But at this point I am stuck because I don't know how to efficiently compare the rows of the consecutive rows without looping through the columns. The end result should give me one value per date-pair comparison, which is the sum of equal entries minus the sum of unequal entries. For this example it would be comparing the 11th with the 12th, the 12th with the 13th and so on and yield: -2, -2, -2, 2. I have a lot more observations per day and a lot more days, so the faster the better. Maybe I already went wrong with the format change... looking foward to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the data in a long format. `match` Time to a time 24 hours later. Use index to get the next Zone. Check equality of Zone and next zone. Calculate difference. Sum result by date.

```
sample[ , v := {
  e = Zone == Zone[match(Time + 24*3600, Time)]
  e - !e}][
    , sum(v), by = .(date = as.Date(Time))]
         date V1
1: 2019-11-11 -2
2: 2019-11-12 -2
3: 2019-11-13 -2
4: 2019-11-14  2
5: 2019-11-15 NA
```

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik works great. Do you maybe also have any ideas how to catch it if days are missing? Is there any elegant way to increase the step size to more than 24h for those cases?

Comment: Great to hear that it worked the day you wanted. For your question, this may sound like a rolling join in `data.table` may be useful. In the `roll` argument, you can specify the maximum time you allow values to roll forward or backward and still consider it a match. If you want an exact match on _time_, but allow the match to occur on different later _dates_, you would clearly need separate time and date variables (as in your Q). Then specify the join variables in `on`, where "Rolling joins apply to the _last join column_, generally a date but can be any variable" (`?data.table`).

Comment: I'll try that thanks. One last follow-up: If it wasn't consecutive days but all possible combinations of two days, how would you approach that?

Comment: Then it sounds like `combn` may be your friend. Note the `FUN` argument, function to be applied to each combination, e.g. compare Zone.

Comment: Little update on the missing days issue: Instead of using `roll` I ended up using `shift` on time and specified `n` to the desired number of observations per day. This gave me the correct value even with missing days, as I never miss observations.